# Get error with code 2 while getting data from FQL with friend location

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I query Facebook FQL with this statement

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name,sex,relationship_status,
current_location.country,current_location.city 
FROM user WHERE uid in 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) limit 1000
```

and get this error

```
{
"error": {
"message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 2
}
}
```

I found that this error occure with getting current_location.country,current_location.city

Please could you give me a suggestion.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Check your permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. I think the result from error in Facebook Server.

Thank you.